# Cheap launching objects to orbit

Tags: orbital-motion

Why [slingatron](https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/391496725/the-slingatron-building-a-railroad-to-space?ref=live) hasn't been successful ?

Same thing with gigantic nail clipper. Since we dont need great force when arm length increases, why couldn't we build gigantic nail clipper orbital launcher :) ? Provided of course that we had material able to sustain great compression stress.

Disclaimer, no im not affiliated in any way with creators, dont know them, not even same country. Just thought that idea was cool.

Comment: _Provided of course that we had material able to sustain great compression stress._ You said it.

Comment: Another thing i guess, would be ("if ever"), problematic heat dissipation, since slingatron as well as railgun / any other device would need to launch at speed able to sustain heat during object flight in athmosphere... (which only gets thinner at quite some distance from earth)

Comment: Are you asking why hasn't the *kickstarter for slingatron* been successful, or why hasn't the *idea of a slingatron* been successfully employed? I'm also under how a gigantic nail clipper could be used to *launch* anything.

Comment: Idea, obviously. I guess "wisdom of the people" allows to distinguish good from bad regarding what to finance on kickstarter. Regarding 2nd question, i'm pretty sure You used one of those, what happens with part of nail that gets separated? Gains quite a velocity. I'd probably should seek proper term like lever, applying force from two sides over extremally long arm, but english is not my native language, so i've escaped to graphic(al) expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of the centrifugal force. I had made some calculations back when I was looking for a good MSc thesis subject because I wanted to work on a railgun or a slingshot in orbit but it turned out it was impossible because of that, since it would need an astronomically long arm not to crush everything in the satellite.

You are looking at reaching orbital speeds of several kilometres per second... The centripetal force provided by the arm (or in that case, the spiral structure) and undergone by the structure of the satellite is:
$$F_c=\frac{v^2}{R}$$
Which means that to reach a relatively low speed of 3km/s (GEO), even with a 1km radius the centripetal force is 900kg-f.

Not so big? Take into account the fact that it's very simplified. This is only to reach an orbital speed. In practice the delta V for insertion is different, since you have gravity to battle as you go up and you're doing it less efficiently with a slingshot than a launcher because you don't have a vertical phase at the beginning... And they already require more than 10km/s of deltaV to get to GEO (10tonnes-f!). I let you have a look at [Hohmann transfers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hohmann_transfer_orbit) as a simplistic example to get values.

Comment: Well ok, but we might for example build our way of layered composition of materials, which we would consider "shells" and agree to destroy in process, but still they would pass our force towards the middle (lets call it slug).

Comment: I updated my post with a bit more details. Having a spring/damper (which those multilayers would be) system would indeed reduce that force (I let you calculate it), but it would drastically increase the radius of the slingshot (which understandably couldn't be a spiral anymore). As excited as I would be to see such a system work (I work for the Space industry), I am very skeptical.

Comment: Yup, convincig. Well, not even problems with cetrifugal force to our object we desire to launch, but as well we would need to build this circular sling path with same material...

Comment: Yes, this spiral system raises also the issue of satellites which are not cylindrical, and those are much, much, more common than the "barbecue" satellites as we call them (because they rotate to average the temperature, usually they're solar orbiters). Even those, would roll, and since the solar arrays are on their surface it would damage them if there isn't any protection to eject later in orbit. Etc, etc. The most realistic of those unrealistic subconcepts would be a simple anchor that would unroll as the satellite gain speed before cutting it. But imagine the safety perimeter...

Comment: Well, so here is another idea :) as we know, steam can be oversaturated. What if we build large container allowing steam to build up insane pressure, but ONLY to launch object like 250m above ground. Object would have exact same container attached "igniting" 2nd level steam blow when velocity dropped due to air friction ?

Comment: I updated my post above, I had an error in there (which doesn't change anything to the outcome). Ideas are great, but you're on your way to reinvent the traditional launchers here... (you'll find that steam is not enough, and so use LoX and kerosene instead etc.)

Comment: Ah, always worth a dream, as one's said until you know its not possible, nothing's impossible. Who would have thought about building CERN's LHC with 27km radius ? So maybe in several years we'll face miraculous breakthrough :)